# How to keep image size and position after changing sprite through code multiple times?

Tags: image, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm building a topo trainer in Unity where you have to type the correct State name of a requested State.
If you type the name of a (incorrect) different State, that state will turn yellow.
This works, but only for the first incorrect State you type in. The second wrong State you type in will have the size and image of the previous incorrect State.

tl;dr:
Changing the sprite of an image works once, but the second time the size and position are changed oddly (see pictures below where Florida is the second wrongly guessed State). This is the code I use for changing the sprite of the image.

```
randomImage.sprite = images[num];
```

Where `images` is an array of sprites and `randomImage` is the image hosting the sprites starting off with an empty png image. PS: All images have the same size.

[image]

[image]

[image]

PS: The Rect Transform panel is shown here (with all values 0):

Comment: Well, you never set the position, so how do you expect the position to update?

Comment: Through a script or through a panel? I have the position (Left, Top, Right and Bottom all) set as 0 in the Rect Transform panel. The strange thing is that the first sprite change works out perfect, but the second sprite change gets messed up..

Comment: Rect Transform is just telling Unity how you want Unity to deal with what happens when the parent container changes sizes (e.g. changing the device resolution). It does **not** reposition your Highlight over the area Florida is in your background image just because you changed the sprite to one of Florida.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a whole lot simpler method for you, which will avoid dealing with this issue you've got, whatever it is.

Image has
Image.color

So: make your separate state pictures be white. then they will render in the color you set in their Image.color. Or Sprite.color.

Then, assemble the US in the editor, in the scene, put together all the states so that they fit.

Then, assign all of them from the scene into some List.

Then, instead of spawning the incorrect yellow ones as new Images, just find which one the relevant is, and change its Image.color = Color.yellow

The way you're doing it, you're doing multiple things wrong and it's not obvious what the mistakes are, since you didn't provide enough info, or screenshots that would actually be useful. I recommend remaking the whole thing according to what I said, it's going to be easier and less error-prone.